# Connect an ip behind nat using sockets

Tags: networking, network-programming

Consider a phone which is connected to wifi with phones A, address as Dynamic Ip `ex:192.168.0.34` and its listening over a server socket at `port 7567,` In what way can i connect to that socket using any programming language if i have another phone B to connect that which is on public ip say `10.0.0.56` and i have the wifi router ip say ex `55.56.89.76`  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to connect directly to a client behind a NAT if you don't use port forwarding. But there is a technique called hole punching to open a port thrue a NAT.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching):

> Hole punching is a computer networking technique for establishing communications between two parties in separate organizations who are both behind restrictive firewalls. Used for applications such as online gaming, P2P and VoIP, both clients establish a connection with an unrestricted third-party server that uncovers external and internal address information for them. Since each client initiated the request to the server, the server knows their IP addresses and port numbers assigned for that session, which it shares one to the other. Having valid port numbers causes the firewalls to accept the incoming packets from each side. ICMP hole punching, UDP hole punching and TCP hole punching respectively use Internet Control Message, User Datagram and Transmission Control Protocols. Using TCP nefarious hole punching, it's possible to send compressed SYN packets through into a common ACK path. Numerous software does this.

See also the questions related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Hole%20punching).

Comment: But hole punching is not supported from all routers, right, basically am looking to make a messaging app where on server side i would just maintain a database of ip addresses and port and when a message needs to be shared i just establish a connection with ip and port running a listening socket to receive message

Comment: I think in that case you need a server for forwarding that informations you need.

Comment: and how do i do that can you give me some sample links

Comment: That depends on your server. Which operating system does you use? And which is your favorited programming language?

Comment: linux as os and java as language

Comment: It could be oversized but [JBoss](http://www.jboss.com/products/platforms/application/) could be helpful.

Comment: I would like to write my own server :) Consider I know both the public ip and port of router as well as phone and note it on my server on which request came, now if tcp socket connection is closed but phone is still listening on certain port, can i reestablish the connection and push messages to phone using the public ip and port, if yes then how and if no, whats the alternate solution